# How to connect class User of JHipster with an existing class containg users credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jhipster

I have a project generated with Jhipster(Spring Boot) and I have an existing database with a table "Utilisateur" and this one contains already "username" and "password" and other fields.. I would like to use **authenticate** function of JHipster so that the existing users (in table Utilisateur) can access to thier accounts but I don't know how to do it since **authenticate** function works with User class that also has "username" and "password" fields..
I searched here https://www.jhipster.tech/user-entity/ but doing it with inheritance (Utilisateur extends User) implies to add User fields to Utilisateur table and I don't have to add new columns to Utilisateur table.
Please any simple solution to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Just modify manually the generated code: change the name of table in `User` class and change the Liquibase migration of User table in `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml`.

As you already have a `Utilisateur` table, I would modify Liquibase migration to replace `User` table by `Utilisateur` table. I would not rename the mapped entity as `Utilisateur`, I would keep it named as `User` so that I don't have to change all code dealing with authentication.

You should also change test data in users.csv so that it matches the structure of your Utilisateur table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Please, can I keep Utilisateur entity that uses the Table Utilisateur (this table is already present in Liquibase) because it has ManyToOne relationship with other entities ?

Comment: I edited my answer to cover your point.

Comment: I tried to make modifications but I got errors.. Could you please take a look at my code if I really did what you suggest here is my repo https://github.com/hamaarouf/userAuth (changes on **user** branch)

Comment: You don't say which errors you got and you're asking for help, are you serious? One thing I can say is that you forgot to modify users.csv